# Dominar turns off when I shift to first gear

Tags: motorcycle, bajaj

I own a dominar 400 and I have ridden 11K kilometers (Completed 3 service last month). I had an issue with throttle lag before and the service center said it will be fixed by an ECU update. After the ECU update when you shift to the first gear sometimes, the bike turns off. It can be started again with the self-start and it won't happen If you hold the throttle a little(Kind of like slow speed issue). When it turns of it feels like the fuel is cut off. Also, there is a missing feeling when I ride the bike. I have taken it again to my service center and with not much help (That day dominar service personals where on leave also there attitude is like the bike is still running). This gets little frustrating when you ride in heavy traffic.

**My question is what all specific things should I ask the service personals to check** like on my old bike we could ask to adjust slow speed or replace the accelerator cable etc since this bike is fuel injected I don't know much. The service centers electronic diagnosis couldn't find anything last time, the engine oil level is fine. Mailed bajaj customer care didn't get any reply. So if someone could figure out this could be the issue or you should check these components please help.

Comment: Take it in, describe the symptoms as you did here and let them fix it - if it is not sorted take it back...

Comment: ABS or Non-ABS? refer this [link](https://www.bcmtouring.com/forums/threads/bajaj-dominar-400-abs-ownership-thread.70085/page-36#post-1290670)

Answer (score 1):

Check your kickstand safety switch which grounds out the ignition when it's closed.  It's the same circuit, usually, as the kill switch.  This is a safety mechanism to prevent the rider from driving off with the kickstand down.

Use a multimeter to see if the switch opens or closes the circuit.  You will want to disconnect from the main harness while you test.

If the switch is not having issues ensure the plate that closes the switch on the kickstand is properly hitting the switch and is aligned properly.

There are two possible issues, if it's the kickstand switch, physical or electrical.

Comment: I think it's not the kickstand safety as this also happens during the ride ( If I suddenly shift to first gear) and if it is kickstand it should happen with other gears right? Also, the kickstand indicator is not lit.

Answer (score 1):

Greeting fellow Dominar rider, dominar is seen having this problem of sometimes turning off when switching to first gear either a cold or hot start.

I myself has experienced it. For some users this was fixed after ECU update. In last 2 months it got an ECU update for both ABS and Non-ABS version. Kindly go to SVC and get it updated.

If updating ECU doesn't fixes it. Notice your accelerator when this happens as since dominar is quite heavy it is easy for engine to get stopped when shifting in first gear without much accelerator twisted.

Also dominar is equipped with falling-sensor which gets triggered when bike falls down and kills the engine for safety. If you ever tipped your motorcycle. Sensor might have malfunctioned and is giving false alarms when shifting to first gear. as there is a big jerk due to high torque as you shift to 1st gear.

Kindly check your chain slack too as it can also cause this if it's too tight.

Comment: Hi, I have asked a new question would be glad to know your thoughts.

Comment: Sure. Tysro. will reply that.